# About diamond generation code in Java

Tags: java

This is the work that i done so far, i'manage to do is just create a triangle,So how can i extend this to create a Diamond pattern

```
class Diamond {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");

          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            System.out.print("*");

          System.out.print("\n");}
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the program like this, first you have to keep in mind
that you have to create empty spaces, then only you'll be able 
to create this pattern,this is sample code.You have to create an 
Upside down triangle, like you done so far,

```
class Diamond {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");

      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");

      System.out.print("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 7; i > 0; i -= 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 9 - i / 2; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");

      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");

      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
}
```